# xamarin.Forms scroll only part of the page

Tags: layout, xamarin, scrollview

I have a page where I want to have a header always in view at the top and buttons always in view at the bottom. the content in the middle is scrollable.

I thought that this would be easy by doing the following:

```
StackLayout outer = new StackLayout();

StackLayout inner = new StackLayout();//with all of the content added

ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView();


outer.Children.Add(headerLabel);//non-scrolling

scroll.Content = inner;

outer.Children.Add(scroll);      //scrolling

outer.Children.Add(button);     //non-scrolling
```

The headerLabel and the button stay on the corrrect position but the content scrolls right up to the top of the page, over the top of the headerLabel (but beneath/under the button at the bottom).

I am positive it was working correctly but I can't remember changing anything.

Has anyone got any ideas on why this would be happening?

Comment: inner.Children.Add(inner); Inception? :)

Comment: Had this issue when compiling using Android API version 23 reverted compile and Target to 22 and it fixed it. So could be to do with version of the API you where targeting Or that the target and value are not the same.
@MihaMarkic fix worked as a temporary until I found the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

so this fixed it

```
outer.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.End;
```

and

```
scroll.IsClippedToBounds=true;
```

Comment: Great answer! Works perfectly.

Comment: Hi i have somewhat similar problem? can you look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990161/xamarin-forms-scrollview-keyboard-appears-and-button-also-scroll