# xamarin.forms scrollview keyboard appears and button also scroll

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Hi i have a weird problem.

I defined few labels and textbox for data entry purpose using xamarin.forms.
I wrapped them into scroll view so that when keyboard appears, they should scroll.

It is working fine. The control which has focus scroll to top and the keyboard appears when it get focus. but i also have couple of buttons at the bottom of my form. Now, the problem is, whenever keyboard appears, my bottom buttons are also scrolled. which looks weird. As button are for submit or cancel, it should be stay there in bottom.

following is my code:

```
var firstNameLabel = new Label { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill };              
firstNameLabel.Text = "First Name";

            var firstName = new Entry() { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand };
            firstName.SetBinding (Entry.TextProperty,MyViewModel.FirstNamePropertyName);

            var lastNameLabel = new Label { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill};
            lastNameLabel.Text = "Last Name";
            var lastName = new Entry() { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand };
            lastName.SetBinding (Entry.TextProperty, MyViewModel.LastNamePropertyName);
---- other fields

Button btnSubmit  = new Button
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
                BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#22498a"),
                TextColor = Color.White,
                Text = "Submit"
            };

var cancelButton = new Button { Text = Cancel", BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("0d9c00"), TextColor = Color.White };
            contactUsButton.Clicked +=  (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                // cancel operation
            };

var cotrolStakeLayout = new StackLayout () {
                Padding = new Thickness(Device.OnPlatform(5, 5, 5),0 , Device.OnPlatform(5, 5, 5), 0), //new Thickness(5,0,5,0),
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand, 
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
                Children = { firstNameLabel, firstName, lastNameLabel, lastName, -- and other fields}
            };

var scrollableContentLayout = new ScrollView (){ 
                Content = cotrolStakeLayout,
                 Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Vertical,
                 HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
                 VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill
            };


var buttonLayout = new StackLayout (){ 
                Padding = new Thickness(Device.OnPlatform(5, 5, 5),0 , Device.OnPlatform(5, 5, 5), 0), //new Thickness(5,0,5,0),
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, 
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
                Children= { btnSubmit , cancelButton }
            };


var nameLayout = new StackLayout()
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill, 
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
                Children = {scrollableContentLayout,buttonLayout}
            };

return nameLayout;
```

Any ideas what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your layout to reach your target:
- Define a "Main-StackLayout"
- Create a "Button-StackLayout" for your Buttons (that should stay on top)
- Add your Buttons to the "Button-StackLayout"
- Add the "button-StackLayout to the "Main-StackLayout"
- Add the ScrollView to to "Main-StackLayout"
- Set content of the page to the "Main-StackLayout"
This should work: buttons stays on top, where (only) the ScrollView can be scrolled.